# can't scroll in my Iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, scroll, overflow

I work on an instagram page visible with an iframe, all is ok with this page, my problem is that I can scrolon my iMac but I can't scroll with iPhone or Ipad ?

I check my code and i see any hidden overflow ?

```css
body { overflow: scroll!important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch!important; }


.rightpart { background:#fff; padding-top: 0px!important; padding-bottom: 0px!important; overflow-x: hidden !important; overflow-y: scroll !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important; height:600px; }
```

```html
<link property="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index/font/font.css"/>
    
<link property="stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index/book/jquery.fancybox.css">


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="index/js/modernizr.custom.js"></script>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="index/book/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="index/book/fancybox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="index/js/thumbnails.js"></script>




<div class="leftpart"></div>  

<div class="rightpart">

<iframe style="border:0px; min-width: 100%; overflow: hidden; min-height:800px;" src=".../"></iframe>    
    
</div>

    





    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    

    



<script type="text/javascript" src="index/js/functions.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the option `overflow: scroll;` inside the iframe property in css

```
iframe {
     overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: this one is obsolete in HTML5 no ?

Comment: yep added in my page and in my live example but nothing changes !!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using

```
iframe {
     overflow: auto;
}
```

This will make it so the iframe only shows the scroll bar if it is needed.

Comment: added in my page and in my live example but nothing changes too ;(

Comment: @clodo0683 Your code example is working as expected for me. Are you testing it on a phone/tablet? If so can you screenshot what the page looks like and post it.

Comment: I see anyscrollbar after that my page is loaded, when i want to scroll on my iPad and iPhone, in my iPhone 6 last version, i can scroll in landscape but not in portrait ( I don't know why ? ) but in my iPad i can't scroll in Landscape and Portrait !! a screen will be ok ?

Comment: Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to the parent of the iframe and see if that fixes it. Also try creating a fixed height and width for the iframe and container div and check to see if this has any effect.

Comment: so with overflow: hidden; on parent div and a max-height: 30000px for example instead of min-height:99%; i think it works, need some time to updates my code and see it working on Ipad

Comment: i updated my example and my page but it doesn't work yet ?!? i'm blocked because it works fine in my iMac but not in my iPhone (portrait mode ) and iPad (landscape and portrait mode )

Comment: It's ok now with this configuration overflow-x: hidden !important; overflow-y: scroll !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important; height:600px; on parent and width: 100%; overflow: hidden; height:800px; in iframe

Comment: @clodo0683 Glad you got it working. I'd reccommend submitting the code that worked for you as an answer just in case someone stumbles across this post and has a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try add

```
scrolling="yes"
```

to your iFrame tag.